# Inserting ID values from tkinter combobox values

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm fairly new to python and tkinter and I was wondering if it's possible to populate a ttk combobox with two values. i.e. an ID value and its corresponding text value. All the documentation I have read so far say it can only take single list values. I have managed to populate the combobox with values from an SQL Server table and would like to insert the combobox data into another SQL Server table, but would rather insert the ID value and not the string value. Is this possible?

Comment: You can combine the ID value and the string value into single string, like `"1: option 1"`, as the *value* used in the combobox.  Then you can easily extract the ID from the selected value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it out last night and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It can only take a list of strings. However, the strings can be keys to a dictionary. You can easily look up the value based on the string. You can create your own class that handles these details for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try out your solution in the next couple of days.